# Error on loading the xhtml for the first time?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

It happens only sometimes and mostly the first time I load the app.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<partial-response id="j_id1">
  <error>
  <error-name>class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</error-name>
  <error-message>
    <![CDATA[ See your server log for more information ]]>
  </error-message>
  </error>
</partial-response>
```

Any idea of what it can be.

Comment: one tip, please try posting the exception string in Google before posting here. 99% of the cases you'll find relevant info

Comment: yes, I didn't think about the exception for the searh. Thanks